# the time required to decide $L$

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

Suppose that a language $L$ is decided in space $S(n)$ by a DTM with
alphabet  $\Sigma$ and set of states $\Gamma$. What upper bound can you give for the
time required to decide $L$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A deterministic turing machine with alphabet $\Sigma$ and states $\Gamma$ which uses only $l$ tape cells can only be in $$
  N_l = l\cdot|\Sigma|^l\cdot|\Gamma|
$$ 
different configurations (each of the $l$ tape cells contains one element of $\Sigma$, the machine is in one of $|\Gamma|$ states, and the head is positioned over one of the $l$ cells). Thus, if the machine needs $l = S(n)$ tape cells to decide whether a string of length $n$ is in the language, it will do so in no more than $$
  T(n) = N_{l} = S(n)\cdot|\Sigma|^{S(n)}\cdot|\Gamma|
$$
steps. If it took longer than that, the machine would reach the same configuration twice and hence enter an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you. Isn't space $S(n)$ important as well?

Comment: @Gigili Hm, I read "S(n)" as "space complexity $O(n)$" which is why I set $l=c\cdot n$. But you probably simply meant that $S(n)$ *is* the space bound, i.e. the machine needs $S(n)$ cells for an input of length $n$. Will update accordingly.

Comment: Right, thank you. But in an answer I've found it's written that the upper bound is $|\Gamma|S(n)|\Sigma|^{S(n)}$, is it invalid?

Comment: @Gigili No, I forgot to consider the position of the *head* when counting the number of possible configurations. That adds an additional factor of $l$ to $N_l$ and brings things in line with your answers. Will fix.